# Can you omit do when the topic has been raised in a previous sentence?

Tags: questions, do-support, some-vs-any

For example in the following sentence it seems like do could be omitted:

"Is it OK if we don't talk today? Or do you need to chat about something?"

So that this would seem appropriate, maybe:

"Is it OK if we don't talk today? Or you need to chat about something?"

**1 - Is it ok to omit it? If not, why?**

Furthermore, regarding the same sentence, what is more appropriate? Anything or something?

"Is it OK if we don't talk today? Or do you need to chat about anything?"

would be better?

**2 - Any change of meaning? Or tone? Or grammatical problem?**

Comment: This question was also asked here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516275/can-you-omit-do-when-the-topic-has-been-raised-in-a-previous-sentence but judged as off-topic for that forum.

Comment: about "chat about": it seems to be correct. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/chat_1  https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/chat+about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colloquially, we do sometimes express questions simply by tone of voice, without the inversion normally required. So

> You want to chat about something?

is a perfectly good colloquial question. A neutral (less colloquial) form would be

> Do you want to chat about something?

But where the modal is *need*, I find this option much less natural, possibly because talking about what somebody needs is generally less formal than what they want. So to me,

> Or you need to chat about something?

sounds a bit odd, though not impossible.

As for the difference between *something* and *anything*: the difference is very slight. If you use *something*, you are suggesting that the other person has something in particular that they want to discuss. If you use *anything*, you are not making such a suggestion.

**Edit**: I don't find the question of whether the topic has been raised previously to be of any relevance at all to the question.

Comment: Thanks. I commented about it having been raised in the other topic because sometimes people complain about duplicates. So I thought I would just announce the reason why I am still asking it again.

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo: my edit was in response to "when the topic has been raised in a previous sentence" in the title of your question.

Comment: hm, I see. The thing is that for me, when the 'or' is in the sentence, it sounds a bit too much to put the 'do' there. But I guess I have to get used to it.

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo: our intuitions from another language are often not helpful. But the "do" often does not take a whole syllable: in many circumstances, the phrase will come out as /d͡ʒu ni:d/